# Debian - Stop checking in with mirror

Tags: debian

I'm trying to cut back all but essential network traffic from my device running Debian (jessie), because it will be living on a cellular modem.

While watching traffic with `iftop`, I noticed pretty repetitive traffic coming from `repos.quadranet.com`, which I've found to be a http/ftp mirror.

I assumed that this is some sort of mirror watcher that is actively pinging/pulling from this mirror or checking on something, but my google searches on how to turn off mirror checking isn't working.

**How do I disable mirror checking (or whatever it's called) in Debian?**

From comments:

```
# etc/apt/sources.list`

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Just edit your question and add it at the bottom.

Comment: @ojs the configured repisitories aren't really relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, I kind of deserve a PhD on that subject. I had a very limited 3G connection on my last Desktop. Here we go:

- Disable `cron-apt` by deleting `/etc/cron.d/cron-apt`.
- As a general rule, everything under `/etc/cron` will run automatically and might use bandwidth. Check the scripts to decide whether you need it.
- I also would disable unnecessary packages. But that's very personal, what is necessary for me might not be for you.[[1]](https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian#Remove_non-critical_packages)
- Disable daemons which might use the network.[[2]](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon#Enable.2Fdisable_daemons)
- Lastly check the processes having open connections. Kill the ones you don't want running and aren't critical to the system. [[3]](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/network-statistics-tools-rhel-centos-debian-linux/)